# How to convert mongoid criteria to array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a mongoid criteria `categories` and I need to convert to an array. I'm using `categories.to_a` but this dont works and always that the mongoid criteria is iterate by `.map` it's doing a `.find` a new query.

How can I fix this?

```rb
def self.mapOffers (array, user)
    array.map { |u|

      {
      :id             => u.id.to_s,
      :name           => u.name,
      :description    => u.description,
      :price          => u.price,
      :url            => u.url,
      :categories     => Category.mapCategories(u.categories.to_a, user),
      :picture        => u.picture.url,
      :accepts_cash   => u.accepts_cash_transactions,
      :location       => {
        :longitude      => u.longitude,
        :latitude       => u.latitude,
        :street         => u.street,
        :neighborhood   => u.neighborhood,
        :number         => u.number,
        :zip            => u.zip,
        :city           => u.city,
        :state          => u.state,
        :complement     => u.complement,
        :country        => u.country,
      },
      :fixedMeetingPoint => u.fixedMeetingPoint,
      :meetingPoint   => {
        :street       => u.meetingPointStreet,
        :neighborhood => u.meetingPointNeighborhood,
        :number       => u.meetingPointNumber,
        :zip          => u.meetingPointZip,
        :city         => u.meetingPointCity,
        :state        => u.meetingPointState,
        :complement   => u.meetingPointComplement,
        :country      => u.meetingPointCountry,
        :latitude     => u.meetingPointLatitude,
        :longitude    => u.meetingPointLongitude,
      },
      :notes  => u.notes,
     }}
  end
```

```rb
def self.mapCategories (array, user)
    array.map { |u| {
     :id => u.id.to_s,
     :name => u.name,
     :selected => !user.nil? && u.users.include?(user),
     :picture => u.picture.url,
     }}
  end
```

Comment: Could you show code examples showing what you want to achieve? What does it mean that `to_a` doesn't work?

Comment: I provided some code. Can you help?

Comment: What does it mean that to_a doesn't work? :)

Comment: I mean what is actual and what is expected behaviour?

Comment: Mongoid always do a new query when categories are iterate I just need iterate an array and not do more queries because I already have the query result of the offers in `.mapOffers`

Answer (score 1):

Starting from criteria:

```
scope = Band.where(name: 'foo')
```

... retrieve the complete result set from the database and store in an array:

```
bands = scope.to_a
```

... then iterate the array any number of times:

```
bands.each { |band| ... }
bands.each { |band| ... }
```